# Can't load module in Ubuntu - Operation not permited

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If I do:

```
sudo insmod module.ko
```

I get:

```
insmod: error inserting 'module.ko': -1 Operation not permitted
```

modinfo gives me:

```
filename:       module.ko
license:        XXX Proprietary
version:        210
author:         XXX
description:    XXX Driver
srcversion:     XXX
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-33-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 586TSC
```

and uname -a gives:

```
2.6.32-35-generic-pae #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 11 17:01:12 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

so I suspect that I need to install this specific kernel version:

```
2.6.32-33-generic-pae
```

**My question is how to manage to insert this module and if kernel version is the problem - how to install it on Ubuntu 10.04?**

Just to mention, I had 2.6.32.33-generic kernel when I installed Ubuntu, but insmod failed.
Then I did:

```
sudo aptitude install linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
```

and I selected new kernel on boot, but insmod failed again. What I noticed is that it was (I think 2.6.32.36-generic-pae and not 2.6.32.33-generic-pae, but I don't know how to install this specific version)

Comment: Not to ask the obvious question, but I assume you did: "sudo insmod module.ko"?

Comment: Copy your module to the module dir, do a `depmod -a`, then do `modprobe module`.

Comment: @Rilindo: Yes, I used sudo ;)

Comment: Thanks! You may want to update your post from "insmod module.ko" to "sudo insmod module.ko" to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

*From [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/), section 1.2.1.1:*

> A module compiled for one kernel won't load if you boot a different kernel unless you enable CONFIG_MODVERSIONS in the kernel.

So, building a kernel with CONFIG_MODVERSIONS enabled, probably will resolve your problem. Another solution would be to build and install Linux 2.6.32-33 with PAE support.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - I just needed to install "linux-image-2.6.32-33-generic-pae" from synaptic package manager and reboot.

Now inserting module is passing, thanks.